# Creating a State array in React

Tags: forms, reactjs

I'm new to react and I wanted to create a React form with the option to add and delete input fields. Initially i set the number of input fields to 5 in the state like

```
this.state = {
        rowValues : ['','','','',''],activities : '' }
```

and I render them through a map function

```
<Row>
 {this.state.rowValues.map((newrow)=>{
   return (
     <Col sm={12}>   
       <Row className="form-row">
         <Col sm={12}>
            <div className="form-input">
               <InputGroup>
                 <InputGroup.Addon className="activity-ul"><i className="fa fa-circle"></i></InputGroup.Addon>
                   <FormControl type="text" name="ngo-activities-undertaken" placeholder="activities" value={this.state.activities} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,'activities')}></FormControl>
               </InputGroup>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Col>)
     })
   }  
</Row>
```

For each of the input field i have to have a separate activities value. now i get the same state for all the input fields. So how do i have a separate activites state which must be also added when a new input field is added and also removed when a input field is deleted.

the entire code is below

```
          render(){
           return(
<Row className="form-row">
                    <Col sm={8} className="form-activities-undertaken">
                         <div className="form-label">
                            <ControlLabel className="label">Enlist activities undertaken as part of this project<span className="star"> * </span></ControlLabel>
                        </div>
                    </Col> 
                    <Col sm={2}>

                        <Button className="add-activity" onClick={this.addrow.bind(this)} bsSize="sm"> <i className="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</Button>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={2}>
                        <Button className="delete-activity" onClick={this.deleterow.bind(this)} bsSize="sm"><i className="fa fa-minus"></i> Remove</Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    {this.state.rowValues.map((newrow)=>{
                            return (
                                <Col sm={12}>   
                                    <Row className="form-row">
                                        <Col sm={12}>
                                            <div className="form-input">
                                                <InputGroup>
                                                    <InputGroup.Addon className="activity-ul"><i className="fa fa-circle"></i></InputGroup.Addon>
                                                    <FormControl type="text" name="ngo-activities-undertaken" placeholder="activities" value={this.state.activities} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,'activities')}></FormControl>
                                                </InputGroup>
                                            </div>
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </Col>)
                            })
                        }  

                </Row> );}
```

the handleChange function is

```
handleChange(name, e){
    this.setState({ [name] : e.target.value })
}
```

the addrow and deleterow functions :

```
    addrow(){
    console.log("the addrow button clicked");
    var newRow =[];
    newRow = this.state.rowValues;
    newRow.push('')
    this.setState({rowValues : newRow})

} 

deleterow(){
    console.log("the deleterow button is clicked");
    var delrow = [];
    delrow = this.state.rowValues;
    delrow.pop();
    this.setState({rowValues : delrow})
}
```

kindly do help me out .Thanks in advance  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have both row value and activities value for each field, then your state should be an array of objects, one per input.

And when you have a new input you should update the state using something like:

```
newInput = { row: rowValue, activities: actValue};
this.setState(oldState => 
  ({ inputArray: [...oldState.inputArray, newInput] }));
```

To delete an element, define a new array which is a copy of the old one, find the index of the element that you want to delete from the array, and use splice to remove it.
The, set the new array to the state.